# What are some general properties of $F(x, z) = \int f(x, y) f(y, z) dy$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, integration, physics

What are some general properties of $F(x, z) = \int f(x, y) f(y, z) dy$ ?

For example, what can be said about the relation between $F(x,z)$ and $f(x,z)$?

Optical theorem in physics of wave scattering has this form. What other theorems in natural sciences and mathematics also have this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will instead consider the operation taking $f$ and $g$ to $F(x,z)=\int f(x,y) g(y,z)d y$. Everything said below is under mild assumptions, measurability or continuity.

- The operation is associative.
- As Noah observed, when the integral is a sum, it is matrix product.
- For symmetric functions: it induces inner product on space of continuous symmetric bivariate real functions.
- The formula reminds me of [Möbius transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_transform) and [incidence algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra), I think it is a continuous form of this.
- It reminds me also of composition of [relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) and composition of [profunctors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profunctor) in category theory
- Also faintly reminds me of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a detailed answer without knowing which kind of properties you're seeking.  One idea: it may be helpful to think of the analogous definition for $x$, $y$, and $z$ discrete, taking values in $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.  In this case $f$ is a matrix and $F$ is just $f^2$, the matrix product of $f$ with itself.  Depending on your situation this may yield some insights.  For example, if $f$ is a symmetric matrix then $f^2$ is positive semidefinite, and a similar statement should hold for the case of continuous variables if the terms are reinterpreted appropriately.